# MySQL LOAD DATA: Get a non-zero return code if there are warnings

Tags: mysql

```
mysql --show-warnings -e "LOAD DATA INFILE etc etc"
```

Always returns status code 0, even if the import fails and prints a warning for each failed row.

But I'm doing this as part of a automated pipeline, so I need that command to fail and give me an error message, raise an alert.

How can I force MySQL to give me a failure status code, so my pipeline can tell me something went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I need to do something like this, I'll attach `SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS;` to the end of the command. The full thing would look like this:

```
mysql -e "USE {database}; LOAD DATA INFILE '{filename}' IGNORE INTO TABLE {table}; SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS;"
```

Which (for example) would give an output like this:

```
+-------------------------+
| @@session.warning_count |
+-------------------------+
|                       4 |
+----------------------—-+
```

Comment: How would you turn that into something the shell would understand? Do you parse that output and grab the count?